# cycle2 carousel conflict with cycle2 slidershow

Tags: carousel, conflict, jquery-cycle2

Cycle2 carousel conflicting with cycle2 slideshow **at the same page**.
Means i setup two different slider .Each of them having different Images. 
Carousel works fine with **$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.carousel';** and 
Slider works fine with **$( $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector ).cycle();** 
but not at the same page. How to work them at same page?
I 've tried **$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.carousel,.slidershow';** did't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a slideshow and a carousel on the same page. In the slideshow section I used this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( '.cycle-slideshow' ).cycle();
});
</script>
```

In the carousel section I used:

```
<script>
$.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.carousel';
</script>
```